# Python ctypes from_buffer mapping with context manager into memory mapped file (mmap)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, mmap, contextmanager

I'm using `ctypes.from_buffer()` to map a ctypes structure to a memory mapped file for some tasks. Typically, these files contain a concatenation of structured headers and binary data. The ctypes structure allows for a stable binary representation and easy pythonic access of the fields - a real winning team in this respect.

These memory mapped files grow dynamically over time. Apart from the complication of accepting growth in `mmap.PAGESIZE` granularity only, the mmap responds with allergic reactions, if some (hidden) references are kept into the mapped area during resize attempts..

That's where a context manager come into play.

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*

import io
import mmap
import ctypes
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__file__)

def align(size, alignment):
    """return size aligned to alignment"""
    excess = size % alignment
    if excess:
        size = size - excess + alignment
    return size

class CtsMap:
    def __init__(self, ctcls, mm, offset = 0):
        self.ctcls = ctcls
        self.mm = mm
        self.offset = offset

    def __enter__(self):
        mm = self.mm
        offset = self.offset
        ctsize = ctypes.sizeof(self.ctcls)
        if offset + ctsize > mm.size():
            newsize = align(offset + ctsize, mmap.PAGESIZE)
            mm.resize(newsize)
        self.ctinst = self.ctcls.from_buffer(mm, offset)
        log.debug('add mapping: %s', ctypes.addressof(self.ctinst))
        return self.ctinst

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        # free all references into mmap
        log.debug('remove mapping: %s', ctypes.addressof(self.ctinst))
        del self.ctinst
        self.ctinst = None

class MapFile:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self._offset = 0
        try:
            mapsize = mmap.PAGESIZE
            self._fd = open(filename, 'x+b')
            self._fd.write(b'\0' * mapsize)
            self._created = True
        except FileExistsError:
            self._fd = open(filename, 'r+b')
            self._fd.seek(0, io.SEEK_END)
            mapsize = self._fd.tell()
        self._fd.seek(0)
        self._mm = mmap.mmap(self._fd.fileno(), mapsize)

    def add_data(self, data):
        datasize = len(data)
        log.debug('add_data: header')
        hdtype = ctypes.c_char * 4
        with CtsMap(hdtype, self._mm, self._offset) as hd:
            hd.raw = b'HEAD'
            self._offset += 4
        #del hd
        log.debug('add_data: %s', datasize)
        blktype = ctypes.c_char * datasize
        with CtsMap(blktype, self._mm, self._offset) as blk:
            blk.raw = data
            self._offset += datasize
        #del blk
        return 4 + datasize

    def size(self):
        return self._mm.size()

    def close(self):
        self._mm.close()
        self._fd.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    logconfig = dict(
        level = logging.DEBUG,
        format = '%(levelname)5s: %(message)s',
    )
    logging.basicConfig(**logconfig)

    mapfile = sys.argv[1:2] or 'mapfile'
    datafile = sys.argv[2:3] or __file__

    data = open(datafile, 'rb').read()

    maxsize = 10 * mmap.PAGESIZE

    mf = MapFile(mapfile)
    while mf.size() < maxsize:
        mf.add_data(data)
    mf.close()
```

This code creates a fully mmapped file `mapfile`, and copies itself into this file a couple of times, with a header tag ('HEAD') prepended, just for illustration purposes. Usually, the structured header is slightly more complicated...

Running the code results in:

```
DEBUG: add_data: header
DEBUG: add mapping: 139989829832704
DEBUG: remove mapping: 139989829832704
DEBUG: add_data: 3275
DEBUG: add mapping: 139989829832708
DEBUG: remove mapping: 139989829832708
DEBUG: add_data: header
DEBUG: add mapping: 139989829835983
DEBUG: remove mapping: 139989829835983
DEBUG: add_data: 3275
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ctxmmapctypes.py", line 110, in <module>
    mf.add_data(data)
  File "ctxmmapctypes.py", line 78, in add_data
    with CtsMap(blktype, self._mm, self._offset) as blk:
  File "ctxmmapctypes.py", line 39, in __enter__
    mm.resize(newsize)
BufferError: mmap can't resize with extant buffers exported.
```

To get the code working, one has to remove the comments in front of the two del statements in MapFile.add_data.

Obviously, they are necessary, because the variable assigned in the `with` statement still exists in the local namespace, and that is enough to keep a reference into the mmap area, that `mmap.resize()` stumbles upon.

How can I get rid of these del statements, since they are a real PITA, and aren't context managers invented to avoid such contortions?

IOW, is there a way to remove these mappings more effectively? E.g. to revert the operation of `ctypes.from_buffer()` programatically in `CtsMap.__exit__()`?

A related issue, that further illustrates the ctypes.from_buffer, combined with mmaped files approach can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41078754/python-ctypes-hashable-c-char-array-replacement-without-tripping-over-0-byte).

Comment: Hmm, code ran with no error on Windows and created `mapfile`.  Can't reproduce.  Suspect, though, that `self.mm = None` in `__exit__` would release what the `del` is releasing.

Comment: Hm, I'm on Linux (pretty current kernelwise FWIW). Unfortunately, the mmap implementations differ significantly between these two OSes. What I don't grok is the lifetime semantics of the `with` variable. When the `with` block ends, the var gets out of scope, and I thought, this is enough to trigger the destructor, so in theory, the code in `__exit__` is enough. But in practise, with Python 3.4.5 under Linux, it's not. Thank you for testing this under Windows.

Comment: The `with` variable doesn't go out of scope; only `__exit__` gets called. Since `del` fixes things for you, setting the instance variables to None will release those objects.